# Could not resolve 'item.url' from state '' error is given when I try to use ui-sref with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

When I click on the navigation I get the error on the title.

I can see item.name as "Page" on the navigation menu

When I change inside ui-sref into {{item.url}} it gives: Invalid state ref ''

Navigation HTML:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ui-sref="item.url">{{item.name}}</a>
</li>
```

routes.js:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('page', {url: '/page', templateUrl: 'views/page.html', controller: ''});
```

items json:

```
{
"items" : [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Page", "alignment": "left", "url": "page", "sub" : false},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Projects", "alignment": "left", "url": "projects", "sub": false}]
}
```

Comment: You have not declared any state except `page` so what do you expect?

Comment: @fracz Sorry, didn't understand. I am only trying to reach page.html at the moment. What is the problem with it?

Comment: So you should use `<a ui-sref="page">` or `<a ng-href="{{ item.url }}">` if the URLs are inside items (but it will not use your state provider).